# how to change color text when edited in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors

how can i change the color of the text which is being edited. i have a datagridview with values inside. what i want is when the user edit the text inside the cell. it must change the text to red how can i do that?

```
    private void Gridview_Output_CellFormatting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Gridview_Output.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "FontOut")
        {
            Gridview_Output.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = "FontOut";
            DataGridViewCellStyle Cstyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            Cstyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: No still searching for it to change the color of edited text only

Answer (score 0):

This will work for all Columns:

```
private void Gridview_Output_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = Gridview_Output[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

If you want to restrict it simply add a check like this:

```
if (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "yourColumnName")
    cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

If you want to keep the color when the user edits the cell but leaves it with the same value as before use these two events (if your `Tag` is not in use):

```
private void DGV_Points_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = DGV_Points[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    cell.Tag = cell.Value != null ? cell.Value : "";
}

private void DGV_Points_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = DGV_Points[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (cell.Tag != null && cell.Tag.ToString() != cell.Value.ToString()) 
        cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: i want it to change the color if the user edited the text. no typing with red color.

Comment: OK, no problem, simply leave out the CellBeginEdit event and in the CellEndEdit set the ForeColor = Color.Red.. Do you validate the Cells?

Comment: the text its black but after edited, i want it to be red

Comment: i want it to remain black and only change color to red after you edited

Comment: That's __exactly__ what the code above does. Have you, maybe, not deleted the original `CellBeginEdit` event?

Comment: I have tried the code above and it doesn't change the color when you edited the text. e.g Testing. if you change 't' to 'b' i want b to highlighted only. how can i do that?

Comment: Well, that is something completely different then. Definitely very much harder since one needs a) __know/store__ just what the differences are and b) __owner draw__ the text in the cell with different Pens. Also one would need to decide what should happen whit the 2nd, 3rd etc edit?? Anything but simple!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71950/discussion-between-it-forward-and-taw).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show the edited values in red right??

Then do like this..

```
    object previousValue;

    public Form1()
    {
        dgv.CellBeginEdit += dgv_CellBeginEdit;
        dgv.CellEndEdit += dgv_CellEndEdit;
    }

    void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != previousValue) 
              dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    void dgv_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        previousValue = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    }
```